# Why does the author use ‘longer’ but not long here?

Tags: word-choice

Why does the author use ‘longer’ but not ‘long’ here?[image: longer]

Comment: can you please edit to replace the image with typed text.  It will make searching for your question easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example #4 is explaining what prepositions are used in relation to short periods of time, such as a single day or the weekend period (often Saturday and Sunday).

Example #5 is explaining the use of the preposition "in" when referencing longer periods of time (periods longer than those identified in Example #4).

The author could have simply used "long," but chose instead to continue with the context started in Example #4.